# PIP package certificate error

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Good day, may I know why pip package wasnt able to run?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python get-pip.py
Could not fetch URL [1]: https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: the last line implies that PIP is already installed? What happens if you type pip at the command line?

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
sudo systemctl restart ntp
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation here, e.g. what does this command do and why is `ntp` related to the above issue?